# htaccess redirect remove /app/webroot in cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have an htaccess file that I want to redirect the all pages to the another folder. I am using cakephp for the site, except for this folder which I want to redirect.

"/app/webroot/" is added to the new directory so the url is /app/webroot/new/ instead of just new.

I am placing this htaccess file (below) in the "new" directory and want anything at /app/webroot/new/ to redirect to /new/ and remove the /app/webroot/ This folder is independent of cakephp and thus does not need to be processed by cake.

The code below loops and I am not sure why.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/


# If your concerned about direct access to a particular page without the sub-dir 
# you will want to add something like this
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new
RewriteRule (.*) /new/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT place the .htaccess file in `/new/` but in `/app/webroot/new/`.

Comment: It is the same directory sorry I should have said new/ not /new/

Comment: I replicated your directory structure & .htaccess on my machine and it is working like a charme.Are you sure there aren't any other `RewriteRule`s getting in the way? Have you tried [RewriteLog & RewriteLogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLog)?